# Form data not being posted to controller when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok so I have this form in my view:

```
<form id="MyForm">
<input type="text" name="myinput" />
<button type="submit" />
</form>
```

I have the following Javascript at the top of my view, which runs when the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $("#MyForm").submit(
                function () {
                    var url = "Home/TestAjax";

                    var dataToSend = $("#MyForm").serialize();
                    alert(dataToSend);

                    $.ajax
                    (
                        {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: url,
                            data: dataToSend,
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        }
                    );

                    return false;
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>
```

The form is being serialised to ajax correctly, as verified by the alert box. Here is my TestAjax controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public string TestAjax(string data)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) ? "Success" : "Failure";
}
```

The value being returned is Failure, because the AJAX isn't being posted back. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: what model does your view have?

Comment: Not using any models at the moment, trying to get my head around just serializing a form to JSON, posting it to a controller and returning a value. Do you need to use a model?

Comment: what alert is shown here alert(dataToSend);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of your input field is `myinput` not `data`. So make sure you have consistently named the argument of your action as well:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestAjax(string myinput)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(myinput) ? Content("Success") : Content("Failure");
}
```

When you use `$("#MyForm").serialize()` this will return `myinput=some_value` where `some_value` is obviously the value that the user has entered in this input field.

And if you had 2 input fields in your form:

```
<form id="MyForm">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" />
    <button type="submit" />
</form>
```

you would of course write a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action will take as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestAjax(MyViewModel model)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Foo) ? Content("Success") : Content("Failure");
}
```

Also please notice that in ASP.NET MVC controller actions should return ActionResults, not strings or whatever.

Comment: Darin u caught that again ;)

Comment: D'oh, I thought the whole form would be serialised to a single JSON string and passed through as data, thanks very much!

Comment: I have looked about ten times over the JS and C# code and left the HTML aside but sometimes HTML is much important as the rest... +1